# Calculate AUC based on TPR and FPR

Tags: machine-learning, roc, auc, confusion-matrix

I have two equations for TPR and FPR (based on the threshold `t`), for example:

```
TPR = (1-t)^2
FPR = (1-t)^0.2
```

How can I calculate AUC based on this? I'm not familiar with this, and the resources online are mostly theories, can someone help, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing more practical than a good theory! You need to graph TPR against FPR (for example, for $t=0.1$, $TPR=0.81$ and $FPR=0.98$, this gives you one point of the graph). The image below takes 1,000 points resulting from giving 1,000 different values to $t$

[image]

Then you can calculate the area under the curve as an integral. Since we're not likely to have an expression for the curve we've plotted, we should try to approximate it. You can get a reasonable approximation of the AUC by calculating the average height of this graph and then multiplying it by its width ($1$ in this case).

However, in this specific example, we can get the exact value by integrating directly, since it's possible to get TPR as a functión of FPR: $TPR = FPR^{10}$, therefore $AUC = \int_{0}^{1} t^{10}dt = \frac{1}{11}$

Comment: Hi I've got the plot, but I don't know how to estimate AUC? Is there a formula or something? Or an example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can get a quick estimation by calculating the average height of the plot. Calculate FPR for $TPR=0$, $TPR=0.01$, $TPR=0.02$ and so on until $TPR=1$. Its average is a good estimate of the area under the curve. For something more precise, take a look at some numeric integration methods. I've editted the answer to deal with this part too. I hope it helps.